# How Can I Solve this problem( UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 145: invalid start byte

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning, object-detection

I am working on object detection with Anaconda Prompt. I am using Faster R-CNN ResNet152 V1 1024x1024. I controlled all things is okey(correct labeling img , system requirements , downloading all packages). I run training algorithm
`(tensorflow) C:\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection>python model_main_tf2.py --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_resnet152_v1_1024x1024_coco17_tpu-8.config --model_dir=training --alsologtostderr`

I am getting such a problem  `self._read_buf = _pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream( UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 145: invalid start byte`

Showing the problem is in this line

```
  def _preread_check(self):
if not self._read_buf:
  if not self._read_check_passed:
    raise errors.PermissionDeniedError(None, None,
                                       "File isn't open for reading")
  self._read_buf = _pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(
      self.__name, 1024 * 512)
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears the string `self.__name` in the last line contains non uft-8 encoded characters (I belive the charactrer `ý`). Without more of your code it is hard to tell where this comes from, but as a quick fix, try changing it to:

```
  self._read_buf = _pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(
      self.__name.encode('utf-8'), 1024 * 512)
```

Though this will likely cause some messy `\xc3\xbd` characters to appear somewhere as utf-8 cannot encode `ý`. Try to track down where this character is and replace with a `y`, or provide the source of `self.__name` if you need further help.